# can't use javaScript setInterval method

Tags: javascript

i cant use setInterval mehod, i don't know why.
what's wrong with this script, after clicking on stop it doesn't show the result of counter i in the text field.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>test_setInterval</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i = 0;
            var interval;

            function start ()
            {
                interval = document.setInterval("i++", 1000);
            }

            function stop ()
            {
                document.clearInterval(interval);
                output.value = i;
            }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="output" type="text" />
        <input id="start" type="button" value="start" onclick="start()" />
        <input id="stop" type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `clearInterval` and `setInterval` are methods of window, not document. You can call them as `window.clearInterval` or just `clearInterval`.
2. It's better to use function as the first argument for setInterval, not a string with the code, because [eval is evil](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/).

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/9cveg/

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap i++ inside a function.
Also, remove document. before the setInterval.
Now, be careful that this has a bug. If you press "start" twice, `i` will go up by two units every second.
Solved the bug by adding another `clearInterval` in the start function.

http://jsfiddle.net/46kzu/3/

```
    function start ()
    {   
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function(){++i;}, 1000);

    }

    function stop ()
    {
        clearInterval(interval);
        output.value = i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to definition, The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds) and its window's method not document's .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

                var i = 0;
                var interval;

                function start ()
                {
                    interval = window.setInterval("i++", 1000);
                }

                function stop ()
                {
                    document.clearInterval(interval);
                    output.value = i;
                }

            </script>
```

Comment: This still won't work, setInterval will have `1` as a first argument not method which increments `i`.